# Modsecurity only allow access from two particular REFERER HEADERs

Tags: apache-2.4, regex, mod-security

I have a Modsecurity rule which blocks all requests where the browser Referer Header is different from this: `sub1.example.com`.

So basically the rule only allows requests when the Header Referer is `sub1.example.com`:

```
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:REFERER "!@rx (?i)^https?://sub1.example.com/" /
"id:'7001024',phase:1,log,deny,status:404,msg:'Blocking Wrong or Empty Referer'"
```

My question is: How can I modify this rule to also allow requests with a second referer like `sub2.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the best with regex but I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
"!@rx (?i)^https\?://(?:sub1\.example\.com|sub2\.example\.com)/"
```

That would block anything not matching:

```
https?://sub1.example.com/
https?://sub2.example.com/
```

Note: I added some escapes of the `?` and `.`

I also think you could add `t:lowercase,` and you wouldn't have to use `(?i)` in the regex.